# jQuery animations slow in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation

Creating this slider that has vertical transition style that slides in one after the other using multilpe div 'slices' (similarly to the nivo slider). However, animations are very, very laggy in Internet Explorer. Not really sure why and I'm not exactly highly experienced with jQuery. Can anyone give me any ideas why? Struggling to figure out why.

Here you can see the codes (JSbin although not functioning on it): http://jsbin.com/ixuhe4

And an example: http://matthewruddy.com/slider/slider.html

Appreciate anyone who can shed some light on this. IE seems to always been my downfall. Thanks.

Comment: that's a cool effect by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me (IE8) that the slowness just occurs during the first pass through the slide deck. After that the animations seem to be the same as chrome. I think this maybe related to how ie is loading the images. I will check a bit more.

Comment: Could it be something to do with each slice having a background image assigned to it? With the Nivo Slider, the animations don't lag at all in IE.. :/

Comment: If your slider script is taking the image height or width into account and it's still being loaded while you start your first scroll through - that could be a cause for slowness in IE8. I recently had an issue with a custom slider script and an image that took too long to load - it only affected IE8. We don't test in anything prior to version 8.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is just a really slow browser from a DOM and JavaScript point of view.  Not much you can do other than limit the amount of animation within IE8 and lower.

If it makes you feel any better, the animation looks flawless in IE9

Comment: I know, but I don't understand why the Nivo Slider's animation manages to be so seem-less in IE8, where-as mine isn't. I got my basis from some of its codes, but I think I may have missed something..

Answer (score 0):

yes IE's js engine is slow as hell compared to modern browsers.
you could try to resize/crop the images so they fit in the frame since they're pretty big.